# Call stored procedure with multiple result sets with sqlsrv - no error receiving

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlsrv

If I try to call a stored procedure with multiple result sets in PHP with PHP Driver for SQL Server (`sqlsrv` extension), I get result sets until an error occurs but I receive no error. Here is a short example:

Stored procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.pr_testmultipleresult
AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        SELECT 1 AS result1;

        SELECT 2 AS result2;

        RAISERROR(
                     'This is an error' -- Message
                    ,16                 -- Severity,  
                    ,1                  -- State
                 );

        SELECT 3 AS result3;
    END;
GO
```

PHP code:

```php
<?php
        $serverName = "localhost\SQL2012TEST";
        $connectionInfo = array("Database" => "TEST", "UID" => "", "PWD" => "");
        $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
        if ($conn === false) {
            die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }
        $query = sqlsrv_query($conn, '{call dbo.pr_testmultipleresult}');
        if ($query === false) {
            die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }
        do {

            while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query)) {
                // Loop through each result set and add to result array
                $result[] = $row;
            }
         } while (sqlsrv_next_result($query));

         echo "<pre>";
         \var_dump($result);
         echo "</pre>";
```

Result:

```php
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(1)
    ["result1"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(2)
    ["result2"]=>
    int(2)
  }
}
```

If the `raiserror` is called before the first select statement, I get an error in sqlsrv. But if there is only one select before the `raiserror`, I don't get it in sqlsrv.

Is there a configuration I have to add to get the errors?

Comment: Why are you using `RAISEERROR` -  to stop the execution of the stored procedure or to return message to the PHP script?

Comment: The `RAISEERROR` is only for example of an ocurring error in a procedure. If an error occurs I want to know that in the PHP script.

Comment: I use `RETURN -1` in similar situations.

Comment: How can I get the returned value? I tried `$query = sqlsrv_query($conn, '{call dbo.pr_testmultipleresult},array(&$retval,SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT)');` but I always get Error HY105 - Invalid parameter type.

The problem with Error message is with this workaround not solved.

Answer (score 2):

**Explanation:**

When the stored procedure returns multiple result sets, you need to check for errors the result from `sqlsrv_query()` call and the result from each `sqlsrv_next_result()` call:

```
<?php

...

# T-SQL
$result = array();
$rc = 0;
$params = array(
    array(&$rc, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT)
);

$query = sqlsrv_query($conn, 'EXEC ? = dbo.pr_testmultipleresult', $params);
if ($query === false) {
    echo "Error executing stored procedure.".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true)."<br>";
} else {
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query)) {
        $result[] = $row;
    }

    if (sqlsrv_next_result($query) === false) {
        echo "Error fetching a result set.".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true)."<br>";
    } else {
        while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query)) {
            $result[] = $row;
        }
    }   

    if (sqlsrv_next_result($query) === false) {
        echo "Error fetching a result set.".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true)."<br>";
    } else {
        while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query)) {
            $result[] = $row;
        }
    }   

    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($result);
    echo "</pre>";  

    sqlsrv_free_stmt($query);
}

# End
sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```

Result:

```
Error fetching a result set.Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 50000 [code] => 50000 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]This is an error [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]This is an error ) )
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(1)
    ["result1"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(2)
    ["result2"]=>
    int(2)
  }
}
```

As a side note, one available option to [configure error and warning handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-configure-error-and-warning-handling-using-the-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-ver15) is `sqlsrv_configure()` function, but I don't think it is useful in this specific case.

**An optional solution:**

I suggest to use the following approach, which is a possible solution to your problem (at least I'm able to execute a procedure, get all possible result sets and get the result status code).

You need to change the stored procedure and use `RETURN` to exit unconditionally from the procedure and to return an appropriate status. You also need to change the statement in the PHP script and use `EXEC ? = dbo.pr_testmultipleresult` statement with an output parameter to check the status, returned from the procedure. Note, that `sqlsrv_query()` returns the result from the statement execution, not the result from the stored procedure execution.

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.pr_testmultipleresult
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @return int
    SET @return = 0

    SELECT 1 AS result1;

    BEGIN TRY  
        SELECT 1 / 0 AS Result2
    END TRY  
    BEGIN CATCH  
        SET @return = -1
    END CATCH 

    SELECT 3 AS result3;

    RETURN @return
END;
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$server = 'server\instance';
$database = 'database';
$uid = 'username';
$pwd = 'password';

# Connection
$cinfo = array("Database" => $database, "UID" => $uid, "PWD" => $pwd);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $cinfo);
if ($conn === false) {
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

# T-SQL
$result = array();
$rc = 0;
$params = array(
    array(&$rc, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT)
);
$query = sqlsrv_query($conn, 'EXEC ? = dbo.pr_testmultipleresult', $params);
if ($query === false) {
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
do {
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query)) {
        // Loop through each result set and add to result array
        $result[] = $row;
    }
} while (sqlsrv_next_result($query));

# Check result
if ($rc < 0) {
    echo "Result from stored procedure: ERROR";
} else {
    echo "Result from stored procedure: OK";
}   
echo "<br>"."Results:"."<br>";
echo print_r($result, true);

# End
sqlsrv_free_stmt($query);
sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: I changed the initial value of `$rc`to `$rc = -1;` because when an uncaught error in the stored procedure occurs, after the first `SELECT` value would not be changed. It is not the preferred solution for my problem, but is a good workaround. Thanks.

Comment: @MrMirCannae, you may use `TRY .. CATCH` error handling, see the updated answer. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't work. If an error occurs after the first select, there is no more output to sqlsrv. The return in the `CATCH`gets not to the sqlsrv. It's like a cut after error without any notification about an error.

Comment: @MrMirCannae If you want  to continue with the execution and return available result sets, and notification only about the errors, I suggest an additional change in the procedure (small update in the answer).

Comment: @MrMirCannae Additional explanations :). Thanks.